# Showing and Hiding a child component from parent for specific seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have notification component, which is a child component and being shown in parent component after a button click. After a custom seconds of time it will be hidden. So far I have come up with this code (Stackblits).

[MyCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgchj5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnotification%2Fnotification.component.ts)

Parent component:

```
<button (click)="handleClick()">Initiate Message</button>

<app-notification [message]="message" [duration]="3000" [show]="show"></app-notification>

<app-notification [message]="message" [duration]="6000" [show]="show"></app-notification>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
   message:string;
   show:boolean;


  handleClick(){
    this.message = 'Good Morning';
    this.show=true;
  }
}
```

Child comp:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="show">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

```
 @Input() message: string;
  @Input() duration: number;
  @Input() show = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.show)
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.show = false;
      console.log(3)
    }, this.duration)
  }
```

This works perfectly, but after 3 seconds as it is in the example, If I click the button, the child component is not being showed. What am I doing wrong. I am new to Angular, please help me.

Also I want to handle the same for both instances of the child.

Comment: please include the relevant code snippets in the question itself.... links break from time to time and such people who might view this question in the future will not have a way to see the original source code

Comment: @mrtechtroid added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the code for the timeout out of `ngOnChanges`.
In your component setup a setter would do the trick.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.css'],
})
export class NotificationComponent {
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() duration: number;
  @Input() set show(value: boolean) {
    this._show = value;
    // Or find another failsafe if the values are not set as expected
    if (value && this.duration) {
      this._show = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._show = false;
      }, this.duration);
    }
  }
  get show(): boolean {
    return this._show;
  }

  private _show = false;
}
```

As well as an ugly hack to avoid Angular not realizing that this value needs to be reset:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  show: boolean;
  duration: number;

  handleClick() {
    this.message = 'Good Morning';
    this.show = true;
    setTimeout(() => (this.show = false), 1);
  }
}
```

Using RxJS Observables would solve this problem in a nice way, but it would also be more complicated if you are new to Angular.

Comment: I could not understand that, what should I do in `handleClick().`

Comment: You can leave `handleClick()` exactly as it is for this example

Comment: I tried your way, its not working. I might have missed something. Please check this stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgchj5-pbke99?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Please edit here, if I am missing something.

Comment: You didn't move the code from `ngOnChanges` into a setter

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgchj5-2bwcp5?file=src/app/notification/notification.component.ts

Comment: I created another stackblitz, please use the this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zf3ssa?file=src/notification/notification.component.ts)

Comment: I think now I realized your problem, this should solve it (also updated the post accordingly)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ja93gf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: inside setTimeOut, it should be `this._show=false` right?

Comment: Now it is working, why are you doing set time out in handleClick(), can u pls explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244229/discussion-between-maddy-and-leon-hikari).